# How to fix C++ argument of type"const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type"char*"

Tags: string, class, pointers, reference, char

I'm using vs2019 and I have a problem the compiler give me an error however I cant solving that
please help me.
the error is :  argument of type"const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type"char*"

> Blockquote

```
   ***  #include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class part
{
public:
    char partname[30];
    int partnumber;
    double cost;
    void setpart(char pname[], int pn, double c)
    {
        strcpy_s(partname, pname);
        partnumber = pn;
        cost = c;
    }
    void showpart()const
    {
        cout << "\npartname : " << partname;
        cout << "\npartnumber : " << partnumber;
        cout << "\ncost($) : " << cost;
    }
};
int main()
{
    part part1, part2;
    part1.setpart("handle bolt", 467, 4500);
    part2.setpart("start lever", 549, 2300);
    cout << "\nFirst part : "; part1.showpart();
    cout << "\nSecond part : "; part2.showpart();
}***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings you are giving to setpart are const strings ( const char *) . But set part take a char * as parameter. Since pname will not be modified in your example you can replace `void setpart(char pname[], int pn, double c)` by `void setpart(const char pname[], int pn, double c)`

Comment: that's right man but I have tried this before however it didn't work . thank you so much it  works now.